# I would like to create a function that compares the hours from moment to a set of div classes (new to coding sorry if this is worded incorrectly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, momentjs

I can't get this to work creating many if statements by stating if moment.... === 12(example below) but I would like to consolidate it to one by pulling from my div classes labeled 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

```
function hourTrack() {
 if (moment().hour() === 12)
 $(".12").css("background-color", "red");
 $( ".1, .2, .3, .4, .5,").css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

My thought process leads me to believe it should be something like

```
function hourTrack() {
     if (moment().hour() === parseInt(the div id number)
}
```

Am I on the right track? Any help appreciated!

Comment: What are you doing after the `if`? Can you show more of the repetitive `hourTrack` functions?

Comment: yep, just updated my code. I am trying to make color changes to a div once the time has passed or is currently on the time

Comment: So you want to update it frequently? As in the user opens the page at 09:59 it should mark all divs with class .9 and a minute later, at 10:00, it should mark .10? Or only once on page load?

Comment: yep! that is what i am hoping for

Comment: Did you test this anywhere? Perhaps you can recreate it for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this a little differently. Change the HTML so that each element which could be targeted has a class in common. For example, in addition to having a class of `1`, or a class of `2`, these elements would also have a class of `hour` too:

```
<div class="1 hour"></div>
<div class="2 hour"></div>
```

Then you can simply iterate over all `.hour` elements first:

```
function hourTrack() {
  $('.hour').css("background-color", "blue");
  $(`.${moment().hour()}`).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

But also, classes **should not start** with numbers:

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

> a name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers.

So the classes of `1`, `2`, etc, aren't valid. Maybe change to:

```
<div class="hour-1 hour"></div>
<div class="hour-2 hour"></div>
```

and then use

```
function hourTrack() {
  $('.hour').css("background-color", "blue");
  $(`.hour-${moment().hour()}`).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Depending in the HTML structure, you might be able to avoid the standalone `.hour` classes if those elements can already be uniquely identified from a selector.

Answer (score 0):

First, set all classes that match an hour (`.0` to `.24`) and set the background to blue (as in: not the current hour). And then change the current one to red.

```
// An array containing numbers from "0...24"
var allHours = new Array(25).fill(0).map(function(num, index) { return index });
// A string containing all hours as classes ".0, .1, .2 ... .24"
var allHoursAsClasses = allHours.map(function(num) {return '.'+num}).join(', ');
function markCurrentHour() {
   // the current hour
   var currentHour = moment().hour();
   $(allHoursAsClasses).css("background-color", "blue");
   $('.' + currentHour).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

You could even make it so that the current hour is not changed back to prevent blinking issues.

```
var allHours = new Array(25).fill(0).map(function(num, index) { return index });
function markCurrentHour() {
   var currentHour = moment().hour();
   var allHoursExceptCurrent = allHours.filter(function(hour) { return hour !== currentHour})
   var allHoursAsClassesExceptCurrent = allHoursExceptCurrent .map(function(num) {return '.'+num}).join(', ');

   $(allHoursAsClassesExceptCurrent).css("background-color", "blue");
   $('.' + currentHour).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I will try this out as well. I am really interested in learning the different avenues that can be taken to solve a problem.